# Unable to change text() value

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="search_on" id="search-item">
    <span class="text">one</span>
</div>
<ul class="search_item" style="display: none;">
    <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('.search_item li a').click(function() {        
    $('#search-item .text').text() = $(this).text();
    return false;
    $('ul.search_item').hide();
});
```

I want to get:when the user clicks the `a` link which in the `li` label, then change the value in `<span class="text">one</span>` to the value in the a label. Why does the above code not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$('#search-item .text').text() = $(this).text();
```

to

```
$('#search-item .text').text($(this).text());
```

with `.text() = $(this).text()` you are trying to set it like a property but it is a function so you need to call it like `.text($(this).text())`

Answer (score 4):

Change  statement

```
$('#search-item .text').text() = $(this).text();
```

to

```
$('#search-item .text').text($(this).text());
```

and move `return false` statement, after `$('ul.search_item').hide();` if you want to hide `ul.search_item` after setting the text.

Comment: This is correct but it's not the only problem with the OPs code. You will need to move the `return` statement too.

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
  $('#search-item .text').html( $(this).text());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `text()` value as a parameter. like this:

```
$('#search-item .text').text($(this).text());
```